# Can Windows-7 Remote Desktop into a MacBook?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, macbook-pro, remote-access

I want to program on my MacBook Pro from my huge Windows 7 monitors.
I've enabled Remote Login and Remote Mgmt at the MacBook.
MacBook and Windows-7 desktop on same LAN.

Windows-7 Network explorer shows MacBook icon, which I right-click and do "*Connect the Remote Desktop*", but get error: `Remote Desktop can't connect.`

Answer (score 1):

By default a Windows OS cannot remotely login to Mac OS and you must you third party apps for this.

You would need to use something like LogMeIn, TeamViewer, Chrome Remote Desktop or realVNC.

The process you are following will only let you connect to a Mac OS and access its files provided you turn on file sharing ON, on your Mac OS

Answer (score 0):

To access the Mac from a Windows machine, you will need to install a VNC client on the Windows machine, or locate RDP server software for the Mac (not sure if it exists). I use VNC myself since it is ubiquitous, easy to set up, cross-platform and essentially open source. However, be aware that it is not a very secure protocol since it lacks sufficient encryption or even a username parameter. All the same, it is still widely used in secure environments. The VNC protocol can also be hardened by tunneling it through SSH, but that is a topic for another day.

To enable VNC on the Mac, navigate to SystemPreferences>Sharing>RemoteManagement. Make sure this feature is enabled (as you say you have already done). Then click on the "Computer Settings..." button. In the new window, place a check to enable "VNC viewers may control screen with password:" and then set a password.

Back on the Windows machine, install your prefered VNC client and launch the program (I prefer TightVNC). Enter the IP address of the Mac and the password you previously created in the Mac's settings if needed. If you are not asked to supply the password in the VNC client's connection settings, you will be prompted for it after the connection begins to take place.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use a program that can control other **Windows** computer with your Mac. The program you enabled (Remote Mgmt) will likely only work with other Mac computers, as far as I know.

What you can do is use a software that work on both of them, like TeamViewer. Install it on both computer, and you will be able to control either of them from one another, even if they are not on the same network (but they will need Internet access).